# Can't log in after a shutdown apparently deleted my user account

Tags: shutdown, users

Last night, I wanted to shutdown my PC after using it, but when I clicked the power icon, a tiny empty box showed with nothing in it (i.e. there's not Shutdown option)

So I thought rebooting will fix it, so I typed in my Terminal:

> shutdown -P 1

After one minute, the PC got hung for few seconds, and then it suddenly shutdown, without closing any programs or anything, it did shutdown abnormally

Later, I turned my PC on and I was surprised that my user account was deleted!
Plus the background and other settings were set back to their defaults, however the Wi-Fi connected automatically without asking for the password, seems like it was saved

There's the login button with Username/Password fields, I am sure that I typed them correctly but it says invalid credentials

I can sign in as Guest, but I can't do anything administrative, my user folder is still in place, but I can't access it due to being Guest

I have Ubuntu 13.04, dual-boot with windows 8

Comment: what ubuntu version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a duplicate of [Can't login to my user account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274435/cant-login-to-my-user-account), here is what you have to do.

You have to change the ownership of `.Xauthority` so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and try to connect.
If you can't connect with `yousef`, try to connect as root (so as username gives it `root` and as password it might be the same than `yousef`).
Then do

```
chown yousef:yousef ~/.Xauthority
reboot
```

and see if it has worked.
You can also just delete .Xauthority using nautilus if you can login to graphical session (you can install other display manager such as GDM to login, the problem lies in LightDM), or you can delete it via the terminal

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
```

Comment: i have seen this question actually it didnt helped, it stil not working, the root password isnt neither root or my password

Comment: How did you do it without begin connected ? You don't have the permission to do it from a guest account since you have no access to `/home/yousef`. If you go in recovery mode from grub you can reset the root password.