# Can not login in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I have a problem with the login to my user account on Ubuntu. After large and profound research in internet, I have found a lot of similar questions in internet (also here on se). How I understood, the main point is the `.Xauthority` [file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274435/cant-login-to-my-user-account).

```
-rw-------  1 user user   52 Jun  3 13:24 .Xauthority
```

I already change "root" permission of `.Xauthority` to the user permisison (exactly like in the line above), but it doesn't help.
Currently I can login only with my guest account. I have Ubuntu `14.04`. I also tried [another possibilities](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), but nothing help... Please, can somebody recommend some solution...

Comment: what are the permissions of `.dbus`?

Comment: @Rumesh, I have found this: `drwx------ 2 user user 4.0K Jun 3 14:38 session-bus`, is user permission or is it not the same?

Comment: Run the command `ls -lah` are any of the files owned by `root`?

Comment: yes, they are, I have several fiels owned by root

Comment: do any of them start with X?

Comment: I have 3 files started with "x" - .Xauthority, .xsession-errors, .xsession-errors.old. Nothing is owned by root

Comment: Im afraid I dont know how to fix this, You should follow the other answer given

Answer (score 1):

Try logging into the virtual terminal (ctrl+alt+f1, ctrl+alt+f7 to get back). This brings up a login prompt, so enter your username followed by the password. Then you can lauch `sudo startx -- :1` and see the errors there; the new desktop will be on terminal 8 (ctrl+alt+f8). Please post the errors reported by the `startx` command:

```
sudo -i
startx -- :1 &> /home/username/output.txt
chmod -rw-rw-r--
exit
```

Comment: sorry, how I can copy from the virtual terminal?

Comment: Pipe the output to a file (`startx -- :1 &> output.txt`), then from the guest session use the copy menus to get it here

Comment: I did it already, don't have permission, will try it again, probably something was wrong PS confirmed, don't have permission

Comment: look at the edits for giving permision